# Jupyter notebook does not work from a specific conda virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

In order to use libraries installed in a specific conda virtual environment I would first activate it and the call jupyter from it:

```
conda activate my_env
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir ~/Projects/my_dir/
```

However, after cloning and installing a new library

```
cd companys_library
pip install -e .
```

Jupyter became unusable:
 - files and directories in `my_dir` do not appear.
 - creating new folders via the interface (new->folder) does not work (no error message, just not effect).
 - Python isn't even specified in the types of notebooks that can be created via the interface (new->notebooks: it's empty)

Jupyter functionality in the other conda environments is unaffected.

How can I restore the Jupyter functionality in this environment?

Comment: The addition of the library using pip was the only change? Had you seen https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/?

Comment: 1.It was, it worked before that.
2. I will look at that, thanks